# CSS/HTML - Viewport metatag destroys my site styling completely?

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing a serious problem with `viewport` `metatag` while browsing on mobile.

Adding this line to my `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Makes the whole site display everything 10x bigger, won't display background images at all.
What am I doing wrong? This only applies to mobile version.

**After using metatag:**

[image]

**EDIT:**
I'll add another screenshot to show exactly this same part of the page.

[image]

Comment: What media queries do you use ?

Comment: Is it the same site?)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/min-1670px.css">` to link css files with device-specific definitions and `@media (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 736px) and (orientation: portrait)` in css file to define  when it's to be used

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan Yeah, the only difference is I added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` on the second pic...

Comment: this is very strange) can you give us a fiddle?

Comment: @DamianDoman that media query should not be used in this case, right ?

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan Actually you can play around with code since it's live @ http://d0man94.ayz.pl/tartakjoltex/

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Why shouldn't it? Should i use EITHER media queries in css OR the `metatag` `viewport` description?

Comment: @DamianDoman no, i mean that in the example resolution in your screenshots the dimensions do not match the media query so the CSS in there should not render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i found problem)
all of you query start from min-width >700px
you can write @media(max-width: 968px) - and all must work fine
play with query rules

Comment: @media(max-width: 968px) - for example, and
all <script> tag must be write  before close </body>

Comment: Yeap, makes certain point, hopefully this will make me work it out ;)